# Are there any ways of preventing hereditary hair loss in people who have NOT YET shown signs of loss?

Tags: prevention, hairloss, preventative-medicine

Most of the information I have come across online is about preventing *further* hair loss ('genetic alopecia') in people who are already balding or thinning. But I wondered whether there were any methods or treatments available for people who are at risk of hair loss (e.g., one or both parents show patterned hair-loss) but for which the process has not yet started. So 'prevention' in the true sense of the term in preventative medicine.

For example, the two main pharmacotherapies shown to be effective for slowing hereditary hair loss are minoxidil and finasteride (see [this meta-analysis](https://www.jaad.org/article/S0190-9622(17)30306-7/fulltext)). Is there any evidence that taking one or both of these, perhaps at a lower dose, in people at risk of, but not currently experiencing, hair-loss halts the process? Or perhaps there is evidence demonstrating the effectiveness of products  designed to stimulate hair growth (e.g., minerals and oils) compared to some control. Of course, the results may differ between sex.

Comment: This seems to be motivated by a 'personal' interest. Nevertheless, please explain the logic a bit more: as far as the mechanism of action for finasteride is thought to be explained, it already fits your description. Tell us why not. Given the contraindications and side-effects of the drugs named, dosage required to be effective makes purely preemptive intake very unadvisable? If it ain't broke, don't fix it?